# Capturing regex compilation errors

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to set up a service similar to [rubular](http://rubular.com), but with PHP as the language  using the preg family of functions. It will take an input regex, a test string, and run `preg_match()`.

How can I find out if a compilation error has occurred (eg: invalid regex), and if that is the case, what was the error? Normally it will throw warnings like:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset x in ****** on line y
```

`pcre_last_error()` is totally useless here, since it will return 0 (`PREG_NO_ERROR`) if the regex fails to compile.

One option I am considering is to use output buffering to capture the warning, but there's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is to omit the error message with `@`, check the return value and, if `false`, call [`error_get_last`](http://php.net/error_get_last).

You could also write your own wrapper around [`pcre_compile`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_compile.c?revision=300946&view=markup#l6712). It receives pointers for storage of error codes and strings. Shouldn't be too difficult; `preg_match` is a thin wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check for regex compilation errors in PHP by registering your own error handler. I wrote a PHP regex tester that detects regex compilation errors and reports them to the user without displaying sensitive information such as file names and line numbers. The key part here is that a custom error handler can trap regex compilation errors. You don't have to throw the exception or catch it. The rest is a convenient demonstration.

I use set_error_handler() to register a function that throws an ErrorException. I catch the exception when running preg_match(), then use the trace information to verify that the exception was thrown from the same file, line, and function that I run preg_match() from (if not, an error or exception was caused by something else like a different function call in the same line or PHP running out of memory). Then I output only the error message to the user.

Note that this script actually runs the regex function using a variable function. Enter the input, the regex without the leading and trailing slash, and any modifiers separately.

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: monospace;
        }

        input[type=text], textarea {
            letter-spacing: .25em;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: larger;
        }

        textarea {
            width: 100%;
            height: 25%;
        }

        fieldset {
            display: inline;
        }

        .error {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="document.getElementById('patterninput').focus();">
    <?php
        // Translate old-style PHP errors to OO approach
        // http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php
        function testRegexErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext) {
            throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
        }

        $pattern = isset($_REQUEST["pattern"]) ? $_REQUEST["pattern"] : "";
        $mods = isset($_REQUEST["mods"]) ? $_REQUEST["mods"] : "";
        $input = isset($_REQUEST["input"]) ? $_REQUEST["input"] : "";

        $regex = "/$pattern/$mods";
        $fns = array("match" => "preg_match", "matchall" => "preg_match_all");
        $fnKey = isset($_REQUEST["function"]) ? $_REQUEST["function"] : "matchall";
        $fn = isset($fns[$fnKey]) ? $fns[$fnKey] : "preg_match_all";

        try {
            set_error_handler("testRegexErrorHandler");
            $result = $fn($regex, $input, $matches);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            // $ex is used later
        }
        restore_error_handler();
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" size="100" id="patterninput" name="pattern" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($pattern); ?>" placeholder="Pattern" />
        <input type="text" size="10" name="mods" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($mods); ?>" placeholder="Modifiers" />
        <fieldset><legend>Function</legend>
            <label for="fnmatch">preg_match()</label><input type="radio" name="function" value="match" id="fnmatch" <?php echo $fnKey == "match" ? "checked" : ""; ?> />
            <label for="fnmatchall">preg_match_all()</label><input type="radio" name="function" value="matchall" id="fnmatchall" <?php echo $fnKey == "matchall" ? "checked" : ""; ?> />
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        <textarea name="input" rows="10" placeholder="Input"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($input); ?></textarea>
    </form>
    <br/>
<?php
if(isset($ex)) {
    $trace = $ex->getTrace();
    if(is_array($trace) && isset($trace[1]) && is_array($trace[1])) {
        $errFn = isset($trace[1]["function"]) ? $trace[1]["function"] : "";
        $errLine = isset($trace[1]["line"]) ? $trace[1]["line"] : "";
        $errFile = isset($trace[1]["file"]) ? $trace[1]["file"] : "";

        if($errFn != "" && $errFn == $fn && $errLine != "" && $errLine == $ex->getLine() && $errFile != "" && $errFile == $ex->getFile() && get_class($ex) == "ErrorException") {
            $regexErr = true;
        }
    }

    if(empty($regexErr)) {
        throw $ex;
    } else {
        echo "<p class=\"error\">The following error has occurred and is probably an error in your regex syntax:<br/>" .htmlspecialchars($ex->getMessage()) ."</p>\n\n";
    }
}

// result will be unset if error or exception thrown by regex function
//  such as if expression is syntactically invalid
if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"]) && isset($result)) {
    echo "Result: $result<br/>\n";
    echo "Matches:<pre>" .htmlspecialchars(print_r($matches, true)) ."</pre>\n\n";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```