# PHP: What's the best practice for catching PHP errors?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

Some PHP core function don't throw an exception but issue an error instead. In some cases I need to 'catch' that error in order to know at runtime if an error occured.

**Concrete use case**: Check if a pattern is a valid regex for preg_* functions (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535765/capturing-regex-compilation-errors), not mine though)

I know that it's possible to use [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-error-handler.php) to set a custom error handler that throws Exceptions ([Example](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-error-handler.php#112881)). But I would like to avoid setting *my* error handler globally, since I'm working on a library and do not want to change PHPs default behaviour.

My current 'workaround' is to set my error handler before calling preg_*, wrap everything in a try/catch block and reset it the error handler afterwards:

```
    $ex = null;
    $pattern = "invalid";
    $subject = "doesn't matter";
    try{
        set_error_handler('my_error_handler_func'));
        preg_match($this->pattern, $subject);
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        $ex = $e; // invalid pattern
    }
    //finally
    restore_error_handler();
    if($ex !== null){
        throw $e;
    }
```

My preferred solution would be to set the error handler to a specific namespace, but that [does not seem to be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5748862/413531). So I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution to this general problem.

Comment: Have you read the manual?

Comment: @hek2mgl: If there is a part of the manual that answers this question on *architecture* I would also be interested in reading it.

Comment: there is not **best** way, this question is opinion based.

Comment: @hek2mgl providing a link might help..

Comment: @NDM I like to search for "best way to ..." when I'm facing a general problem with no obvious solution. There's a ton of questions like this on SO with really great an helpful answers - most of them explainig very well why this or that particular approach is a good choice for a given problem.

Comment: @Hirnhamster After I commented this I realized that you ask for a good practice than how these functions actually work. I provided an answer showing how I would do it / might do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the execution of the core function into a custom function which throws an exception in case of an error, like this:

```
function my_fun() {
    if(@preg_match($this->pattern, $subject) === FALSE) {
        $error = error_get_last();
        if(is_null($error)) {
            $msg = 'Unknown problem';
        } else {
            $msg = $error['message'];
        }
        throw new Exception($msg);
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using `error_get_last()` to obtain the original error message from `preg_match()` and use as the exception message.

Comment: Because it throws if the pattern doesn't match, which is certainly not what the OP wants? For a person posting obnoxious "RTFM" comments, you certainly seem to not be taking your own advice.

Comment: @Jon Ok, added strict check. You down-vote isn't valid anymore.

Comment: Great! Now the only other thing the OP has to do is carefully go over *every single function call* in their code and wrap it inside such a check. [It might not even be technically possible](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to get the exact error in all cases, but it sure sounds practical.

Comment: Nah, I think I 've had enough.